# Trim Post Content on Home Page

Tags: themes, homepage, previews

Whenever I try out a new theme, I select it depending upon preview, which shows latest posts on Home Page, having only trimmed content with featured image and not all long post content.

However, when I install the theme on my test system, the preview shows full length content, instead of the preview.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your theme folder, open the `index.php` (or, `home.php`, or, `front-page.php`), and find, if there is a function named:

```
the_content()
```

Just change it to:

```
the_excerpt()
```

<sub>**P.S.:** If you can't find `the_content()` in the mentioned file, try searching `content.php`, and in this case, change it with caution. Because in theme TwentyTwelve, it's used with conditional tags for different pages.</sub>

Comment: thanx! will try accordingly :)